# Don't show me some random people I'll work with in Jobs ads

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I just saw a job ad, which instead of presenting some information about the available positions, showed me who I'll work with:

[image]

I bet you don't know these people, and neither do I. Their Stack Overflow profiles have 1 reputation and no activity. Honestly, what's the point in showing me that I'll work with them?

Comment: My question is was this an ad that was generated for them (does the site advertise a company and randomly show one of a set of attributes, one of which being current employees) or did the company deliberately set it up to look like this?

Comment: This would be a cool advertisement if it looked at your activity and matched you up with other users in similar techs that you've interacted with in the past and you might recognize. Otherwise, it seems like mostly useless information. Like, of all the information I could be given about the company, *that* information is the least helpful in my initial inquiries.

Comment: Can the company edit those users?

Comment: Yes, to a degree. The user who manages the company page invites a user by email address to join the company page's profile. Once the invite is accepted the user's profile shows up on the company page and  is part of the pool that can be selected for these ads.

Comment: They get a shot to fame, thanks to you.

Comment: Ironically, I always used to get shown people I *do* know, which was pretty creepy :-)

Comment: I'd reject the company on the basis of the photo before even getting to the people list! It looks like a thumb in the foreground and the office in the background is in a sinking ship.

Comment: @KenY-N: I'm glad I'm not the only one who thinks like that. I requested dozens of such subtle improvements in my company but the answer is always: "it's not important" or "no customer will buy more licenses because of that".

Comment: Hey look it's my cousin, what a coincidence.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

To be completely honest, I agree with you (and I was the original implementer of those ads). These particular ads aren't terribly useful. To clarify: Yes, they are generated, and currently the profiles shown are completely random.

I'll be the first to admit that these ads could be significantly better. And the good news is we're currently working on that! The new Company ads will sport a much better design (the current ones were put together when we had a single designer who IIRC was busy with other things at the time), and will be hopefully much more interesting / useful. I don't have an estimated date for when they'll roll out, but I can say they're getting some love (and about time, too. They haven't been touched in 3+ years).

Comment: *I don't have an estimated date* ... I'm pretty sure you'll deliver in 6 to 8 weeks...

Comment: Are the Stack users at a company really the biggest draw?  Many job seekers are looking to join teams with depth in the area of the (seeker's) interest.  Not only could you (Stack) cut through the noise of cruddy profiles by simply summarizing areas of expertise within a company, but you could also use company expertise features to target job ads in a bunch of creative ways (e.g.  Based on visitors' primary topics of interest.  Questions asked.  Etc...)

Comment: You forgot a picture of the office cat/(/dog/mascot). Or foosball table.

Comment: To be honest. I like to see "whom i will be working with". May be you can add a filter to exclude those users who's rep/activity is lower than a specific threshold.

Comment: Is this going to work like linkedin? Show the top-viewed female profiles to all male browsers, and the other way around?

Comment: @RobQuist - Stack Overflow doesn't have a field to indicate gender in your profile. Besides, so far the only thing people have talked about doing was making the profiles shown more relevant to the user.

Comment: @Shyju agreed, it would be useful information in the case of someone with a reasonable amount of activity

Comment: SO profiles(active users) gives me an idea about the level of knowledge/enthusiasm (up to an extent) they have. That is what i am interested to know. Not the gender!

Comment: *"Currently the profiles shown are ... generated ... and completely random... "* Wait, what?  Are you saying that SO job market advertising works like an affinity fraud scam?  Don't stoop so low just because other marketers do it.  That's a real shame because then SO loses out on an opportunity to provide truthful signaling between the workers and the companies in the job market.

Answer (score 21):

Should definitely add some sort of minimum barrier to entry like the user must have X rep, a picture, or profile information.

That ad as displayed would make me actively *not* want to work at that company. Maybe you could sprinkle in some Jon Skeets or Marc Gravells. =)

Comment: "You'll work with the guy who worked with another guy who knew Jon Skeet on some forum".

Comment: @Neolisk sounds to me like you're proposing a Skeet-Number.